# Calculator in Python doesn't update with a "Entry". It's a GUI calculator

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a GUI calculator. I have used the module tkinter. I made it so that it prints in the terminal but when I try to update it in an `Entry` it doesn't update. What shoud I do?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.total = DoubleVar(value=0.0)

        l_uno = ttk.Label(master, text="Nº 1 = ").grid(row=1, column=1)
        l_dos = ttk.Label(master, text="Nº 2 = ").grid(row=1, column=3)

        self.uno = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.uno.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.dos = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.dos.grid(row=1, column=4)

        self.bsuma = ttk.Button(master, text="+", command=self.suma).grid(row=3, column=1)
        e_resultado = ttk.Entry(master, textvariable=self.total).grid(row=1, column=5)

   def suma(self):
       data_error = False
       try:
           resultado = float(self.uno.get()) + float(self.dos.get())
           print (resultado)
           self.total.set(result)
       except:
           data_error = True
root = Tk()
alfa = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please do **not** delete your questions after you've received an acceptable answer. Your questions aren't just for your benefit, they should also be available to help future readers.

Comment: I'd add that deleting your question is very uncourteous towards the person who took their time answering your question. And if you can get in trouble for your question staying visible, you shouldn't have asked it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation result is being bound to the name `resultado`, but you are calling `self.total.set` with the non-existent name `result` instead of `resultado`. But your code doesn't report this error because you disabled the error messages with your "naked" `except:` clause. When catching exceptions it's a Good Idea to use named exceptions, so that you only catch the things you intend to catch, and the `except` block should use the information that the Exception object provides.

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.total = tk.DoubleVar(value=0.0)

        ttk.Label(master, text="Nº 1 = ").grid(row=1, column=1)
        ttk.Label(master, text="Nº 2 = ").grid(row=1, column=3)

        self.uno = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.uno.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.dos = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.dos.grid(row=1, column=4)

        ttk.Button(master, text="+", command=self.suma).grid(row=3, column=1)
        ttk.Entry(master, textvariable=self.total).grid(row=1, column=5)

    def suma(self):
       data_error = False
       try:
           resultado = float(self.uno.get()) + float(self.dos.get())
           print (resultado)
           self.total.set(resultado)
       except ValueError as e:
           print(e)
           data_error = True

root = tk.Tk()
alfa = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

I've also made a few other minor changes to your code. I got rid of the `from tkinter import *` wildcard import statement. And I got rid of the assignments to the names like `l_uno`. The `.grid` method returns `None`, so those assignments are simply saving `None` to those names, they aren't saving the widgets. But since you don't need to keep a reference to those widgets there's no need to perform any assignment. When you *do* need to keep a reference then you need to define the widget on one line and make the `.grid` call on another line, like you did with `self.uno` and `self.dos`.